# How to set a range for elements within an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I´m still very new to C#, we are supposed to use for-loops not methods. My question is how to limit values (1 to 25) that users puts in.
"The game" is supposed to ask a user to put in his values then it throw´s a random number and checks if it´s among numbers kept in myArray.

```
{
int[] myArray = new int[10];

Console.WriteLine("Write down your numbers");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type in values for index nr {0}: ", i);
```

> //user is asked to put in 10 values, what I need to do is to limit and
>   save as elements values in range between 1 and 25, so the loop continues (i++), if user types in a number that is outside that range my loop supposed to go a step back as if (i--)

```
        myArray[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    var rand = new Random();                                     //a random number is thrown

    int rand1 = Convert.ToInt32(rand.Next(0, 25));              //random number ranges between 0 and 25

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", rand1);

    for (int i = 0; i < tal.Length; i++)                //checking if random number is among users inputs
    {
        if (tal[i] == rand1)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("The random number {0} is among 
               your values", rand1);
        }

        else
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Random number isn´t among your 
                                 numbers");
        break; 
        }
}
```

Comment: There´s a missing part that i didn´t even start coding in it. I´m mising a loop that supposed to save values in range or take a loop a step back if values exceeds that range.

Comment: A `do/while` loop will work: `do { myArray[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());} while myArray[i] < 1 || myArray[i] > 25;`

Comment: While I don't have 10 elements, Ask for a number. If the number is in the correct range add it to the list. (Bonus take a data structure that doesn't allow duplicate value so you can easly avoid checking for duplicate eg: {1,1,1,..,1})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type in values for index nr {0}: ", i);
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result) && result >= 0 && result <= 25)
            {
                myArray[i] = result;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong number!");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you try to maintain an index `i` that indicate your current position in the array.
One of the solution will be to simply drop it and  add item to a collection till you have 10 items.

Here I took a `HashSet<int>` because we can't have duplicate in [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8). 
Any time you try to add one, it will simply drop it. But If you want to allow duplicate you can use a simple `List<int>`.

```
int collectionSize = 10;
int lowerBound = 1, upperBound = 25;

var userSelectedNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

while (userSelectedNumbers.Count() < collectionSize)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter an int between {lowerBound} and {upperBound} : ");

    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (int.TryParse(input, out int value)
        && lowerBound <= value
        && value < upperBound
        )
    {
        userSelectedNumbers.Add(value);
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid input!");
    }
}
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(
    $"userSelectedNumbers contains {userSelectedNumbers.Count()} elements : {"
    + string.Join(", ", userSelectedNumbers) + "}"
);
```

You can then validate if the random numer is within the range using [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8) :

```
var random = new Random();
int computerPick = random.Next(0, 25);

Console.WriteLine("Computer picked : " + computerPick);

if (userSelectedNumbers.Contains(computerPick))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You win!");
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("You loose!");
}
```

Don't forget the using :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

nb: The range is define using `1 ≤ x < 25`, using W. Dijkstra convention http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF

Comment: Thank you @Drag and Drop! Your solution seems very elegant and effiecient, but I´m not on that level yet, so I can´t use it anyways. But thank you for oppening my eyes for new possibilities!